# My fadeIn/fadeOuts are overlapping and messing up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

At the very bottom of this page, under the "What is Body Condition Score?" section:

http://tn-2017-12-vrshealth.pantheonsite.io/tn-2/

When you move the slider at a slower speed, the pet images change as they should, however if you move the slider too fast, the animations don't finish, and the images begin to overlap.

Is there a way I can force all of the animations to complete, or queue up properly?

Comment: could you create snippet or fiddle for that ?

Comment: jQuery has its own functions: `stop(), finish(), dequeue(), clearQueue()`. Search in the DOC. If you want more specific answer, then you have to post a minimalistic sample replicating your issue. No one on SO is paid to debug your website...

Comment: @A. Wolff you are right. I'm sorry- in this case I wasn't really sure what to ask for. I appreciate the kindness in telling me about stop() because that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if one of your img are animated , using [:animated](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) otherwise trigger the animation .

So in your silde function should be like :

```
slide: function(event, ui){
   // check if no 
   if(!$(".pet-image img").is(":animated")){
      //annimation code here 
   }
}
```